# Reason for "Maximum recursion error" in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this program describing an algorithm for the simulation of a partial differential equation. The basic functions I use are defined by

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import integrate, stats


def shift(func, x, a=0):
    return func(x-a)


def scale(func, a=1):
    return a*func


def trunc(func, x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return func(x)


def quad(func, a, b):
    return integrate.quad(func, a, b)


def gauss(func, t, x):
    def pregau(z):
        k = (-t ** (1 / 2)) * z
        return shift(func, x, k)*math.exp(-(z**2)/2)

    fa = (1 / ((2 * math.pi) ** (1 / 2)) * integrate.quad(pregau, -np.inf, np.inf)[0])
    return fa
```

The program then simulates the solution to the partial differential equation by

```
def vundl(x, u, l0=0.0, a=a, b=b, c=c):
    v = [u(x)]
    l = [l0]
    f_temp_rec = u
    for i in range(10):
        def f_temp(x):
            y = x - c * dt + B[i + 1] * 2 * a
            z = b * dt
            return gauss(f_temp_rec, z, y)

        li = l[i] + quad(f_temp, 0, np.inf)[0]
        l = np.append(l, li)

        if x <= 0:
            v = np.append(v, 0)
            f_temp_rec = 0

        else:
            f_temp_rec = f_temp
            v = np.append(v, f_temp(x))

    return [v, l]


def u0(x):
    return stats.beta.pdf(x, 2.7, 3.05)


print(vundl(x = 0.5, u0))
```

If I run this program for N=0 it produces a vector. Running the program for N>0 gives me the following error:

"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

but it actually should give me a vector v and a vector l.

Comment: You are not reaching the end of your function before the heap gets full. You have maximum number of function calls within each other that you're allowed to do before running out of heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do in `vundl` with `f_temp` and `f_temp_rec`, but in the `else:` block you assign:

```
f_temp_rec = f_temp
```

and then call `f_temp` which calls `gauss(f_temp_rec, z, y)`.  Since at this point `f_temp_rec is f_temp` the function `f_temp` calls itself in an infinite recursion.

You should be able to see in in traceback that `f_temp` is calling itself repeatedly.

Comment: ```vundl``` should return an array with values at index  0,....,N, and the values of entry i depends on the value i-1. So in ```f_temp``` I start by using u0 and then I want to use f_temp of step i-1 in step i.

Comment: The function itself or the return value thereof? I don't really understand.

Comment: Regardless, this is why you are getting an infinite recursion.